# Is it possible to open the device default mail composer with blank email address?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mailer

I have tried

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:"));
```

but the result is an exception thrown because there is no email address specified as "mailto:name@domain.com".

What I need is just open a blank email composer, that is, with blank subject, body, to:, cc: etc. it's ok to have from: field.

Or should I resort to native implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If that exception is in there, there probably is no way around it.

Instead of inventing the wheel again yourself have a look at the [Xamarin.Plugins.Messaging](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md) NuGet package. It can compose e-mail messages as well as other types of messages. I'm not a 100% sure but you could try to create an empty e-mail with that and save you the trouble of implementing it yourself.

Comment: Case closed then? ;)

Comment: Yah, should I close it? People might still have some answers to do this in Forms rather than using Dependency service.